# Add logo image at footer of email using Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i m trying to add logo to end of email (in regards section), but i am able to send only image link , please help me out, thanks in advance, appreciating your valuable time.

Here is my code

```
    public function sendMailToClient(){
    $subject = "park Group of Hotels.";
    $message = '
    <p>Hello'.$this->input->post('add_name').', <br>Greetings from park!<br> Thanks for choosing Hotel park! We aim to make your stay luxurious and comparting.
    <br>
    we will call and confirm you soon.You can also reach us on _+91 973255 </p>

      <br>
      <br>

    <div style="font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    Regards,</div>
    <div style="font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;color:rgb(0,0,0)">
    park Group of Hotels</div>

    <img src="/hotelempark/assests/img/Logo_1.png" alt="Hotel Empark">


    ';

    $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");                
        $this->email->from('abcd@gmail.com'); 
        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));

        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);

        // $this->email->cc('another@example.com');
        // $this->email->bcc('and@another.com');


        $mail= $this->email->send();
        if($mail>0){
          $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Thanks for Booking Room In Our Hotel, We will Call You Soon');
          $this->email->to($this->input->post('add_email'));

        }else{

          show_error($this->email->print_debugger());

    }
  }
```

email is sending successfully but i images are not loading.

Comment: What images exactly? There don't seem to be any images in that code

Comment: Sir please check, i have edited the code, sorry for miscommunication

Comment: The image doesn't show up because on the mail client `/hotelempark/assests/img/Logo_1.png` does not exist. You need to use your full domain `<img src="https://example.com/hotelempark/assests/img/Logo_1.png">` (or embed the image) so the mail client knows from where to load the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message = '
<p>Hello'.$this->input->post('add_name').', <br>Greetings from park!<br> Thanks for choosing Hotel park! We aim to make your stay luxurious and comparting.
<br>
we will call and confirm you soon.You can also reach us on _+91 973255 </p>

  <br>
  <br>

<div style="font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;color:rgb(0,0,0)">
Regards,</div>
<div style="font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12pt;color:rgb(0,0,0)">
park Group of Hotels</div>

<img src="https://www.Yourdomain.com/hotelempark/assests/img/Logo_1.png" alt="Hotel Empark">


';
```

**You just have to change your URL and add base URL.**